X11 apps from docker in a wayland session
I am running a wayland session on gnome 36. I am unable to get a display output from x11 apps running in docker. It works in --net host mode, but I need to use --net bridge mode.
I am trying to run x11 apps e.g. xeyes from within a docker container.
docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=${DISPLAY} image-name /bin/bash
xeyes

I get the following error
Error: Can't open display: :0


I have set DisableTCP=false in /etc/gdm/custom.conf.
I run xhost +local:docker before running the container.
I have tried different option for the DISPLAY env variable being passed on to docker: :0, 172.17.0.1:0.

The only way I am able to get the display to work is using socat.
socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=172.17.0.1:0 image-name /bin/bash

I think it may be that Xwayland is not listening for the display request in the first case.
But is there any way to get display output without socat.

There are enough steps, limitations, and non-portabilities that I'd probably try to avoid running a desktop application in a container.  If nothing else, it looks like you're not passing the X socket or .Xauthority file into the container, which could be a direct cause of the error message; see Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?

I have tried the following command as well and it does not work docker run -it --rm --env DISPLAY=172.17.0.1:0 --env XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY --volume /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --volume $XAUTHORITY:$XAUTHORITY imagename /bin/bash

I suspect the linked question will help you.  $DISPLAY should not include an IP address, you should never run xhost ever, and you don't need to change Docker networking options here (you're only using a Unix socket and nothing TCP-based).  There's some further discussion there around modifying the .Xauthority file to work in a container.
